# Path field not available in Search API View

Tags: search

Why is the "Path" field not available in a Search API view? Is there another way to get the path for each row in this type of view?

Answer (score 0):

`\/organize$`

`\/`: forward slash escaped

`organize`: letters "organize" matches the characters "organize" case sensitive.

`$`: Must be the end of the string.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vKGYAB/1)